# call spring component method without AOP processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a class

```
@Component
public class A {

   @MyAnnotation
   public Object methodA() {
     // ..
   }

}
```

`@MyAnnotation` - has around AOP processing which means that `methodA` cound be not called at all

I have two business flow when `methodA` should be called:

1. with specific processing which check presents of `@MyAnnotation` and can abort `methodA` invocation
2. `methodA` should be called despite presents of annotation

how can I call `methodA` with ignoring of annotation?

I know about solution where I can create `methodB` which calls `methodA` but this is not my case.

Comment: I think you want it the other way around: put the business logic in methodB, and make methodA simply call methodB

Comment: Please edit your question and show both cases when the method is to be called or blocked from calling, also explain what condition it depends on. Please also show your aspect. Then I can easily help you change the aspect's pointcut so it lets the method call pass through under the right condition.

Comment: Hello, anyone there? If you ask a question and someone tries to help you with hints and follow-up questions, maybe some feedback would be helpful.